# How to configure Karaf org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg to use a sift appender based on the log4j2 logging category

Tags: apache-camel, log4j2, apache-karaf

I'm using Karaf and Camel and have been able to configure PAX logging to sift on MDC fields (camel.routeId) and that works just fine.

I'm wondering if I can configure log4j2 to sift on the logging category field (%c or %logger in log4j2 conversion pattern terms) or if anyone can point me in the right direction as to how I could go about configuring it.

Comment: log4j2 is "sifting" on the basis of MDC data. By default logger/category is not part of this context data. You can however put the logger name to MDC yourself

Comment: Hi @GrzegorzGrzybek, thanks for the comment - it answers my question. If you post it as an answer, I'll be happy to accept (even if I do feel a bit dumb knowing the solution was staring me in the face this whole time...). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4j2 (pax-logging-log4j2) is "sifting" on the basis of MDC data. By default logger/category is not part of this context data. You can however put the logger name to MDC yourself.

In pax-logging-log4j2, [org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.internal.PaxLoggerImpl#setDelegateContext()](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.logging/blob/logging-1.11.3/pax-logging-log4j2/src/main/java/org/ops4j/pax/logging/log4j2/internal/PaxLoggerImpl.java#L361-L374) method sets 3 *keys*:

- bundle.id
- bundle.name
- bundle.version

Camel sets own keys (like `context-id`) in `org.apache.camel.impl.MDCUnitOfWork` constructor.